# It is common to see passwords as plain text over post request?

Tags: post, encryption, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to web development and don't fully understand how encryption on the web works. I was messing around with Chrome Dev tools on the site hltv.org. I noticed when I log in it sends a post request to /login with my password and username visible in plain text in the body of the request. Is this information visible to anyone who could intercept the post request or is only visible to me? Do I have a misunderstanding of how the information is encrypted in https requests?

Comment: If you are using SSL with TLS 1.2 required (older versions disabled on the server) then sending plain text in POST data is secure.  That does assume SSL is not compromised by something like a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: short answer is yes, it's normal to see password as a plain text in POST request.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) shows the *local* representation of code and traffic, visible to the browser. You're seeing the `POST` request your browser is making **before** it gets encrypted and sent to the server (show in plaintext for debugging and development purposes). It is the **browser itself** that encrypts your data (using the [NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/An_overview_of_NSS_Internals) API in Chromium and [Schannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/win32/secauthn/secure-channel) in Windows). This happens before the data leaves your machine, meaning that it will be ecrypted before it ends up on any other machine, even in the case of a man-in-the-middle attack.

No-one else can read this data, assuming:

- you do not have any malicious plugins actively installed in your browser
- you do not have any malware on your computer that can intercept [Trusted Root Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store)